# Can the loss of KMeans increase?

Tags: loss-functions, k-means

Let's say we have a dataset, and we run KMeans with `k` clusters.
Is it possible that during the execution of KMeans the loss first decreases and than increases until converges to a value?

At first, I thought the loss would only decrease, however after some measurements on a personal implementation, for a particular dataset it happens the behaviour before explained.

Here a figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are various algorithms in use to find a (local) minimum of the $k$-means objective function. Most of these (such as Lloyd's) will indeed always decrease the objective function, but there may be an algorithm that doesn't (even though a behaviour as you show isn't very helpful and it makes me wonder whether a better algorithm should be used). In any case this depends on what exact algorithm you're using. Also it may well be that you did something wrong, and the problem is not the algorithm.